# ul based nav not working in iOS Safari / Chrome

Tags: html, ios, css

Weird problem with a navigation area. It works on all desktop browsers, but not on iOS Safari and Google Chrome. Tapping the links does nothing, although tap-and-hold will show the popup-menu asking to open the link in a new window, so in that case it does get recognised as a link.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
 <h1>Site title<span><a href="/"></a></span></h1>
 <ul>
    <li id="nav-reserveren"><a href="/reserveren/">reserveren</a></li>
    <li id="nav-kalender"><a href="/kalender/">kalender</a></li>
    <li id="nav-interieur"><a href="interieur/">interieur</a></li>
    <li id="nav-contact"><a href="/contact/">contact</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#nav h1 {
   text-indent: -9999px;
   font-size: 0;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 451px;
   height: 81px; /*same as span height*/
   position: relative;
}

#nav h1 span a {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   display: block;
   width: 451px;
   height: 81px;
}

#nav ul {
   position: absolute;
   left: 461px;
   top: 14px;
   list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li {
   display: inline;
}

#nav ul li a {
   float: left;
   height: 60px;
   text-indent: -9999px;
}

#nav ul li#nav-reserveren a {
   width: 203px;
   background: transparent url(../img/nav/reserveer.png) top left no-repeat;
}

#nav ul li#nav-kalender a {
   width: 109px;
   background: transparent url(../img/nav/kalender.png) top left no-repeat;
}

#nav ul li#nav-interieur a {
   width: 96px;
   background: transparent url(../img/nav/interieur.png) top left no-repeat;
}

#nav ul li#nav-contact a {
   width: 90px;
   background: transparent url(../img/nav/contact.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

**Edit: solved.**
The problem was setting the opacity of the links in jQuery:

```
var navLink = $('#nav ul li a');
navLink.css('opacity', '0.8');
navLink.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', '1');
});
navLink.mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.8');
});
$('#nav ul li a.active').css('opacity', '1');
```

Moving this over into straight CSS did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

As h1 is a block element with relative and ul is absolute. the ul tends to go under the h1 making the links not clickable.

-> add display:inline-block to h1
or
-> add some z-index (above 1) to ul

Either one should fix the issue.

Comment: That makes sense and appears to have solved the issue (I say "appears" because my iPad is showing a cached version, so I could only check on my iPhone, where the links do actually work properly). Thanks Chetan!

Comment: Scratch the above :( I thought this would solve the problem, but having reloaded the .css file directly on the iPad, then reloading the page, I still have the same problem...